# Mini-Profiler add external timings

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using an MVC 3 application that uses business logic that contains timings in the response.
Now I would like to add these timings to the Mini-Profiler in my MVC3 app on a specific level.

I have tried it like this:

```
profiler.StepStart("key", "value");
var response = GetXXXResponse(request);
if (response != null && response.Timings)
{
    foreach (var child in response.Timings)
    {
         var profiler = new MiniProfiler(child.Name, _profilerService.Profiler.Level;
          profiler.ClientTimings = new ClientTimings { Timings = new List<ClientTimings.ClientTiming> { new ClientTimings.ClientTiming { Duration = child.ResponseTime, Name = child.Name, Start = 0 } } };
           _profilerService.Profiler.AddProfilerResults(profiler);
     }
}
profiler.StepStop("key");
```

I'm using Mini-Profiler version 2.0.2, in the UI I see the steps being added, but the timings are incorrect. 
How can I Profile in MVC a specific function and add extra timing information for that block provided by the external process that cannot be changed?

Comment: https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Timing.cs is pretty mutable, you can clean it up there

Comment: Ok overlooked this Timing class, now I'm able to nest external timings correctly. Thanks!